# displaying data from json in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to display a list of restautants on the home page, but in the restaurant model I have an error in the constructor section. and on the homepage there is also an error that says "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'." snapshot.data section, can you help me solve it.

model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class RestaurantDetail {
  final Restaurant restaurants;

  RestaurantDetail({this.restaurants});

  factory RestaurantDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return RestaurantDetail(
      restaurants: Restaurant.fromJson(json['restaurants']),
    );
  }
}

class Restaurant {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String description;
  final String pictureId;
  final String city;
  final double rating;
  final Menus menus;

  Restaurant({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.description,
    this.pictureId,
    this.city,
    this.rating,
    this.menus,
  });

  factory Restaurant.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Restaurant(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      description: json['description'],
      pictureId: json['pictureId'],
      city: json['city'],
      rating: json['rating'],
      menus: Menus.fromJson(json['menus']),
    );
  }
}

class Menus {
  final Foods foods;
  final Drinks drinks;

  Menus({
    this.foods,
    this.drinks,
  });

  factory Menus.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Menus(
        foods: Foods.fromJson(json['foods']),
        drinks: Drinks.fromJson(json['drinks']));
  }
}

class Foods {
  final String name;

  Foods({this.name});

  factory Foods.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Foods(
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}

class Drinks {
  final String name;

  Drinks({this.name});

  factory Drinks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return new Drinks(
      name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}

List<RestaurantDetail> parseRestaurant(String json) {
  if (json == null) {
    return [];
  }

  final List parsed = jsonDecode(json);
  return parsed.map((json) => RestaurantDetail.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

homepage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:restaurant/data/restaurant.dart';
import 'package:restaurant/style/theme.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/article_list';
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
            .loadString('assets/local_restaurant.json'),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final List<RestaurantDetail> restaurants =
              parseRestaurant(snapshot.data);
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: restaurants.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return _buildRestaurantItem(context, restaurants[index]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRestaurantItem(
      BuildContext context, RestaurantDetail restaurantDetail) {
    return ListTile(
      contentPadding:
          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
      leading: Image.network(
        restaurantDetail.restaurants.pictureId,
        width: 100,
      ),
      title: Text(restaurantDetail.restaurants.name),
      subtitle: Text(restaurantDetail.restaurants.city),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Two questions: Which dart version do you have in your pubspec.yaml file (for example I have: `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"`? Are you intentionally using null safety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code has a lot of complaints since it is actually not written to support null safety. In case you are still not familiar with null safety, you should pick a lower dart sdk version in your `pubspec.yaml` file. I checked your code with this dart sdk version

```
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

and the analyzer found no problems with it (no warnings or red underlined code). Null safety is supported from this version onwards:

```
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
```

With it, you will get null safety warnings. So, in case you did not have chosen this version on purpose, and you don't want null safety, I should recommend picking a lower version. For instance, as said, `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"`. `String?` indicates that a `String` is nullable. To indicate that a variable might have the value null, we add `?` to its type declaration. For more reference, and in case you do want to support null safety, I recommend checking this guide on [Sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think I might be too careless since it's my first time using it. Once again, thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome! Please let me know if, after further research and maybe some refactoring, you still face any issues! If my answer solved your problem or was helpful in finding a solution, I'd thank you if you accept it by clicking on the check mark.